# Should commit messages be written in present or past tense?

Tags: version-control, coding-style

So which is it that you think is better and more intuitive?

```
Fixed the XXX bug in YYY
Fix the XXX bug in YYY
Fixes the XXX bug in YYY
Fixing the XXX bug in YYY
```

Please provide your rationales.  Note I am asking from your general perspective, meaning you should not try to associate this with your preferred svn/cvs tools or programming languages, but rather think of it as something that should/can be applied to any tools and programming languages.

Comment: Someone at your work is too pedantic, I hope it isn't you.  Whoever it is should consider the present perfect vs. the present imperfect, and the philosophical conundrum of whether the commit comment is read as if from the time it was type, or the time it was itself persisted to the repository.  If the latter, use present perfect for a completed action.  If the former, use imperfect for an incompleted present activity.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598/suggestions-for-a-good-commit-message-format-guideline

Comment: Not a dupe of that question.  This is asking about one small aspect, not overall guidelines.

Comment: Fortunately, it is not.  I was asking, trying to find out, would like to know what is the general practice out there.  If I have to tell you the truth, this is actually the most insignificant question I have ever asked on SO, but hey, it is still a question, isn't it?  The question itself has gained three votes, which (if not obvious to you) tells that I am not the only one out there who is thinking that this question is valid in itself.  I am after constructive answers and you are not being helpful at all.

Comment: If you thought that people shouldn't worry too much about tenses in commit messages, well say it, state your reasons and your preferences.  Much more useful and helpful than your sarcastic comment above.

Comment: calm down dude, it's not a serious question (I'm not saying it isn't a valid question) and they were joking around with it.  Lighten up.

Comment: I take this question very seriously. Its a great question. Being consistent is very important when developing software, and being so should be of interest to all the visitors interested in the topic of this website. That is my opinion.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580013/should-i-use-past-or-present-tense-in-git-commit-messages

Comment: See also http://www.exquisitetweets.com/collection/hugovk/1258 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/6602/9001 http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/56031/25708 http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/157590/25708 http://stackoverflow.com/q/3580013/724176

Answer (score 40):

I think of these messages as they appear to other developers.  They don't yet have the changes applied, and there is the implicit question, "what will applying this changeset/patch do?"  It will "Fix the XXX bug in YYY"!

For other verbs writing them as a command seems more natural, and works better if you have a specific goal up-front—you can literally write the commit summary along with up-front tests before the work is done.

I don't put a huge amount of weight on it, but for me this is the path of least resistance while maintaining consistentency.

Comment: I remember coming across something in the git documentation strongly recommending this tense, but I still find in awkward.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3580764/1127485) is the piece of Git documentation is comes from.

Answer (score 33):

I personally go with past tense ("fixed") since by the time I get to committing the bug is fixed (or I wouldn't be committing).

Comment: Can you give an example of this?

Comment: an example of this.

Comment: It's called 'Commit History'. History is always written in the past tense. So past tense makes more sense. When you are going through some repo's commit history also, you are looking at what was done to it... in the past!

Comment: @Shiva Actually every Git guide says you write commit messages in present tense, as the message is not about what has been done but about what this commit **is** doing once you apply it to your checkout. It only becomes history, **after** you have applied it but the first time you read it, you have not yet applied it and so it did not yet happen.

Comment: @Mecki Everything in the branch being pull requested is already history within the branch. The commit messages will be timestamped at the same points in history as they were in the merged branch (when not squashed). In a pull request I am asking to merge the history of my branch to the history of the main branch. When reviewing, you are viewing what has already been done. If you ask questions about the branch, I will explain what I have done, not what I will do once merged. If you approve, we agree that the branch also happened in main. If you reject, then we agree that it did not happen.

Comment: @OvalOlive But it isn't history in your local checkout until you pulled it. So when you look at the commit log on the server from your local checkout, those messages tell you what WILL happen to your local checkout if you pull them and not what did happen, as so far it did not happen.

Comment: @Mecki The commit messages tell what happened in whatever branch you are pulling from. It is history in that branch, hence called a log. You know the history will be added to your history as per understanding Git, and whether the commit message is in present or past tense should hold no cognitive overhead. I know most Git guides recommend present tense and I will write commit messages in whatever style the repo is in. But I prefer writing and reading past tense and I think most people default to past tense unless told otherwise. Most repos I have joined in my work history have been past tense.

Comment: @OvalOlive But it did not happen in your local copy until you perform the pull. So when you read the commit log of the server, this log tells you what the pull will do when you apply it to your local copy, which you may choose to not or even never do.

Comment: @Mecki Why is this not an equally valid perspective: 1) It did not happen in your local copy until you perform the pull -> thus it is not in the log of your local copy until you do. 2) When you read the commit log of the server, the log tells you what has been done on the server -> thus it should be in the past tense on the server. 3) If you do pull -> what was done on the server becomes what was done on your local copy. 4) If you do not pull -> nothing enters your log. 

Essentially, why should your perspective during pulling be the determining factor for the tense in commit messages?

Comment: @OvalOlive Nothing has ever been done on the server. You don't work on the server, everyone works with a local copy. When you write a commit message, this message is supposed to tell other people, what this diff you created and will commit to the server is going to do. It's not up to you to decide which change will ever make it anywhere. You may not even have permission to commit to the release branch. The commit message describes the effect of a diff and an effect is not past  tense, that's why every Git guide you will find online says that commit messages are to be written in present tense.

Comment: @OvalOlive Think of it that way: If you created an image of a tiger and distribute it, will you name it tiger.jpeg or "tiger in comic style.jpeg" or will you name it "I drew a tiger in paintshop.jpeg"? The commit message is the NAME of the diff. It names the effect that diff has. A name is never past tense. A commit log is not a story, a commit log is a list of applied effects.

Comment: The commit message is not unequivocally the effect of a diff, it is whatever the community of a repository chooses it to represent. Why is describing the effect a or name of a diff superior to describing what has been done? You described a commit log to be a list of applied effects (past tense), not a list of "apply if you will effects". In other fields logs are usually in past tense. "tiger.jpg" would be the name of the project (repository) and if I had a log for it I would log steps of what has been done to the image in past tense: "added colour", "applied sharpening filter", etc. (commits).

Answer (score 13):

I prefer to see commit messages in present tense. That way the message describes what the diff does (because you might pull that diff or even that whole commit into a different branch). Thus, the commit message does not describe what it "did" do... It describes what the commit itself "does" do. So it should be in present tense.

Imagine looking at a diff in isolation and trying to decide whether you will apply it. It makes no sense for it to have a title in the past tense.

Comment: "what the diff does" but the diff is created by a commit which was __commited__, it's in the git history already, so it was already "applied".

Answer (score 9):

IMHO if you want it to be descriptive without need to consider the context, then "Fixed" is definitely the only right variant.

Regarding the intuitiveness - if I look at some changelog I will definitely understand that you mean the bug fixed as I know the context in which the word is used, but my brain will catch it much more quickly if the word is written in this self-specifying way.

"Fixing" is the worst choice IMHO as it can be interpreted not only as describing what the patch does (is for) but as a bug status as well which would mean that it is being worked at and is not yet solved.

Answer (score 8):

```
Fix the XXX bug in YYY
Teach the XXX to be more ZZZ
Correct typos in javadoc
```

In general:
    {imperative verb} the {affected object} {optional qualifiers}

Imperative form fits all use cases when I'm considering a patchset.

- What are you going to do here?
- What does this patchset do?
- Why was this patchset created? (to fix the xxx bug...)
- I need to fix the xxx bug in yyy.  Is there a commit on another branch that does this already?

Regardless of your choice, I find consistency helps readability immensely.  Pick one and stick with it.

Comment: Very good reasons.  I always consider it as if the message is saying "I am a patch and I [message]".  That way you always start with an imperative verb.

Answer (score 5):

I think that writing about the current commit in present tense is a good idea, because it makes it more clear when you refer to prior commits in the past tense.

Comment: I agree. If the commit refers to itself it is also true, as in "This commit fixes the F00F bug".

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it really matters. The purpose is to:

1) Convey what is or was being done, so bugs can be found easier, problems can be reverted easier, and generally be able to maintain the project easier.

2) Convey what tickets were fixed if any, so auditors (if they're used in you company can see what changes correspond to which tickets).

Lastly, if it's' already been fixed, "Fixing" doesn't make sense, and if you're still working on it, "Fixed" isn't correct.

Comment: Sure, strictly speaking, it is true that it doesn't really matter.

But if you have to pick one, when you have fixed a bug in your local tree and want to commit the changes made, do you say "Fixed XXX" or "Fixes XXX" or "Fix XXX"?

Comment: I think it matters if the text is too brief. Sometimes I see commit messages that make me wonder whether 1. a bug was found or actually fixed, or 2. whether a fix was concieved or actually applied, or 3. whether complex erroneous behavior was partially or actually fully fixed. And sometimes several commits relate to the same bug. In "This commit fixes the bouncy problem in DrawBall() and closes ticket 666" the tense doesn't matter, because the text is verbose. But for "DrawBall() bounces wrong", what did the commit do?

Answer (score 2):

I think `"Fixes XXX bug"` makes more sense than `"Fix XXX bug"` if the reason for using the present tense is to *"make it more descriptive of what the commit does"* rather than what the committer did.

Answer (score 1):

"*Fix bug X*" is 2 characters shorter than "*Fixed bug X*".
And 3 shorter than "*Fixing bug X*".

From the point of view of writing-short-commit-messages, the present tense sometimes / usually saves a few characters?
Which I actually think matters a little little bit e.g. with Git's recommendation of less-than-50-chars-on-the-first-commit-message-line.
Also, less text --> done reading quicker?

Answer (score 1):

A commit message describes why you wrote the code that is being committed.

"Fixed issue 3124", or "Fixes issue 3124" seems right because it says this code fixed|fixes issue 3124.

However, the grammar may also depend on why marks the bug as fixed. If you can mark the bug as fixed after committing, then "Fixed" is just fine, but if the bug is going to be marked as fixed by someone else after they verify your code, then "Fixes" may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most important answer to such a question is: Everybody should use what works for a specific project and keep it at least a tiny bit consistent.

While I see the advantages of using the present tense (and in fact stumbled upon this post because I’ve seen some present tense messages in open source projects), I probably never won’t use the present tense for my projects. It’s the recommended way for Linux and Git, and probably other bigger open source projects, but I honestly don’t care as long as I’m not part of these projects.

I’m an indie dev and I use the first line of a commit message for release notes while the description in the following lines gives me an idea about implementation details. It’s a user centric workflow compared to the present tense, developer based approach. I can save some time this way. It would be extremely unnatural to give my users instructions in the release notes. It’s my job to fix bugs and to add features. I have to save time, because I’m an indie. I don’t have a “release notes writer” in my team.

Use the rules of a project if they’re already established, but stay pragmatic, and do whatever will make your work easier or faster.

Answer (score -4):

If it is a small commit I use present continuous:

> Fixing bug 304

or

> Adding comments

If it is a big commit, I do more of a change log:

- Fixes Bug 453, 657 and 324
- Adding Expression syntax
- Refactored the Operator class.

Comment: in other words you mix all of them willy-nilly B-)

Comment: Pretty much.   Because in the end, the commit messages don't need to be the queens English.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing many different things in one commit anyway.